# Use new operator to initialise an array

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I want to initialise an array in the format that uses commas to separate the elements surrounded in curly braces e.g:

```
int array[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

However, I need to use the new operator to allocate the memory e.g:

```
int *array = new int[10];
```

Is there a way to combine theses methods so that I can allocate the memory using the new operator and initialise the array with the curly braces ?

Comment: An array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In the new Standard for C++ (C++11), you can do this:

```
int* a = new int[10] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
```

It's called an *initializer list*. But in previous versions of the standard that was not possible.

The relevant online reference with further details (and very hard to read) is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm). I also tried it using GCC and the `--std=c++0x` option and confirmed that it works indeed.

Comment: +1 I don't think the op has a C++11 compatible compiler, otherwise I'd have accepted this answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That's alright... And indeed, according to the [C++11 support matrix](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport), GCC seems to be the only major compiler so far that supports initializer lists.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `memcpy` after the allocation.

```
int originalArray[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int *array = new int[10];
memcpy(array, originalArray, 10*sizeof(int) );
```

I'm not aware of any syntax that lets you do this automagically.

Much later edit:

```
const int *array = new int[10]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Comment: Or equivalently, `std::copy(originalArray, originalArray+10, array)`, there's not much to choose between them. In C++11 you can do `std::end(originalArray)` in place of `originalArray+10`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Does this mean the array holds size info in C++11?

Comment: The type of the array includes the size, same as in C++03. `std::end` is specialized for arrays, with the old `T *end(T (&ra)[N]) { return ra + N; }` trick. There's no new information stored for runtime access, and it wouldn't work if `originalArray` were a pointer.

Comment: Correction: overloaded, not specialized (since it's a function template, it can't be partially specialized).

Comment: How can you achieve the same effect if array is pointer to const?