# Compiler error while implementing a stack data structure

Tags: c++, stack

I've been trying to implement the stack structure using the code:

```
//Implement a stack data structure, and check whether it is empty or not
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct stack{
    int size;
    int top;
    int arr[];
};
void isEmpty(struct stack s){
  if (s.top==(-1)) cout << "Stack is empty";
    else cout << "STack is non-empty";
}
int main(){
    struct stack s;
    s.size=50;
    s.top=-1;
    s.arr=(int *) (malloc (s.size*sizeof(int)));
    s.arr[0]=9;
    s.top++;
    isEmpty(s);
}
```

However the compiler gives an error in this code:

```
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:18:7: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
   18 |     s.arr=(int *) (malloc (s.size*sizeof(int)));
```

Can someone explain what is the problem with this code?
|     ~~^~~

Comment: With C++ the `new` operator is preferred over the use of the `malloc()` function. `malloc()` is a holdover from the C programming language. This has nothing to do with your error but merely a note about expected or current usage.

Comment: If you are using `malloc()` you need to define `arr` as `int *arr;` and not as an array.

Comment: Ah, I am new to C++ programming but I will take care of that from next time. Can you suggest me what should the correct code look like?

Comment: @RichardChambers But isn't arr[] and *arr one and the same thing?

Comment: No `int arr[];` and `int *arr;` are not the same thing.. Are you doing C or C++? The are really two different languages these days though they share some syntax. Th C++ complier is much more strict about these things.

Comment: I shifted from C to C++ today @RichardChambers

Comment: Can you tell what's the difference between the two?

Comment: `int arr[];` is a flexible array which doesn't even exist in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C language with C++ and while there C++ uses much of the syntax of C, C is a small subset of C++. These days the use of C language constructs within C++ programs is frowned upon and it can often lead to problems.

Your `struct` definition is:

```
struct stack{
    int size;
    int top;
    int arr[];    // int array of an unknown length
};
```

If you are to use the `malloc()` function the definition of `arr` should be `int *arr;` because the `malloc()` function returns a pointer to a memory area if it is successful. The important thing to note is that it is a memory area of some size in bytes. That memory area doesn't really have at type.

However in C++ you would use the `new` operator to allocate a memory area. The `new` operator is C++ and what the standard, library version of `new` returns is a constructed object with a particular type. See [Use new operator to initialise an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603696/use-new-operator-to-initialise-an-array/9603754)